# Progress Dialog while page is WebView is loading

Tags: android, android-webview, android-tabhost

I have WebViews imbedded in 3 different tabs and I want to show the progress dialog until the webview in that tab is loaded. I have gotten it to show, but not dismiss. I am trying to do it in the onTabChanged method. Here is my code:

```
mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            if("TAB_1".equals(tabId)) {
               webview2.reload();
               webview3.reload();

            }
            if("TAB_2".equals(tabId)) {
               webview3.reload();
               }
            if("TAB_3".equals(tabId)) {
              webview2.reload();

            }
        }});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify a [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebViewClient%28android.webkit.WebViewClient%29) and override [onPageFinished()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) to dismiss the progress dialog.

Comment: Here is what I have to get the progress dialog to apprear:
     
    if("TAB_2".equals(tabId)) {
                 webview3.reload();
                ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(mainmenu.this, "", 
                          "Loading. Please wait...", true);
                 }

Is there a way that I can say if progress = 100 then pd.dismiss()?